# c++ map insertion error with custom key

Tags: c++

Hi i have custom key defined as shown below. When i create a std::map, i was under the impression that map will refer to operator== defined in my key to detect if two keys are same, but its not true. Can you please point me to correct logic for eliminating duplicates from this map?

```
class Key
{
public:
    Key(char * init, long l): equipNumber(l)
    {
            memcpy(initials, init, sizeof(initials));
    }

    bool operator==(const Key & other) const
    {
            bool result = true;
            cout << "Comparing: " << initials << " with " << other.initials;
            result &= (!memcmp(initials, other.initials, sizeof(initials)));
            cout << " And result is: " << result << endl;
            cout << "Comparing: " << equipNumber << " with " << other.equipNumber << endl;
            result &= (equipNumber == other.equipNumber);
            return result;
    }

    bool operator<(const Key & other) const
    {
            bool result = true;
            result &= (equipNumber < other.equipNumber);
            return result;
    }

private:
    char initials[5];
    long equipNumber;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map` calls `operator <` (or the given comparison functor) twice to determine equality: `! (a < b) && ! (b < a)` implies `a == b`. As it happens, the first less-than operation of the pair is already performed as part of recursive descent, so there isn't much (or any) extra cost. And it greatly simplifies customization.

By the way,

```
        bool result = true;
        result &= (equipNumber < other.equipNumber);
        return result;
```

should probably be just `return equipNumber < other.equipNumber;`. And operations involving type conversions work more consistently with non-member overloads, so it's a good habit to define binary operators as `friend` or outside the `class {}` block.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by "more consistently" ?

Comment: @Jimm The left-hand side is dispatched to the `this` implicit argument of the operator, so it isn't eligible for user-defined conversions. The right-hand side does see user-defined conversions, so you could have `a<b` defined but `b<a` undefined, or mismatched meanings, when `a` and `b` have different types.

Answer (score 2):

A `map<>` orders keys according to [Strict Weak Ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html).  Strict Weak Ordering is based solely on a less-than type comparison.  (Follow the link for a complete definition.)

Notably, Strict Weak Ordering considers objects a and b *equivalent* if `!(a < b) && !(b < a)`, and `map<>` relies on that property.

If you do not provide a comparison function to `map<>` when you create the map, its comparison function defaults to `std::less< Key >`, which will invoke your `operator<`. That means it will not ever invoke your `operator==`, but it will invoke `operator<`.  As long as your class is [LessThan Comparable](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/LessThanComparable.html), then `std::less< Key >` will obey the properties of Strict Weak Ordering.

Comment: The equality operator is not needed at all. It isn't part of LessThanComparable. The relevant page from that site is [this](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/LessThanComparable.html), but all that is obsolete and pre-standard. (It does say the greater-than operator should be implemented, at least if read in the same sense that the ISO standard is written. It still says nothing about equality, though.)

Comment: You are absolutely. I originally wrote it without the `operator==`, and then I second-guessed myself after scanning the SWO page.  Two objects are considered 'equivalent' if `!(a < b)` and `!(b < a)`.  (And note _equivalent_, not _equal_.)

Comment: "SWO" is not relevant to the question at all. That is a requirement of functors, which OP did not implement.

Comment: How is it not?  The question was "why doesn't `map<>` call `operator==` for my key type?"  Keys to `map<>` are SWO.  The default comparator for a `map<>` is `less< key >`.

Comment: No, the comparator functor is SWO. In this case the comparison is set by default to `std::less< Key >`, and `Key` is LessThanComparable.

Comment: Ah, yes, this is C++, where hairs are routinely split finely.  I will adjust my wording above.

Comment: Moving the requirement from the key to the comparator allows multiple orderings to be defined on one type. So you can sort one `std::map< std::string >` according to ASCII collation and another according to localized collation, without making another string type. Also, you can use a type with no operators defined as the key by supplying your own functor, which would otherwise require subclassing classes possibly intended to be "final."

Comment: Ok, I think I've adjusted my wording appropriately.